# Is the extra attack from frenzy on the profile of the Vargheist?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

Vargheist have frenzy. Frenzy gives an extra attack. The profile for vargheist says it has 3 attacks. Does the profile include the extra attack from frenzy or are they supposed to have 4 attacks with frenzy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Vargheist is supposed to have 4 attacks. Its profile states it has 3 attacks naturally, and then you add 1 for the frenzy special rule.

This is due to the unit being able to lose Frenzy, and as such losing the extra attack, without changing the unit's baseline.

This is the same for other units such as Witch Elves, and dual wielding units, with the extra attack being added to the unit without changing the unit base stats.

Comment: Also don't forget it also gets a stomp... I love Vargheists!